# Uncaught ReferenceError: Error not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have this jqgrid code below and I have a picture inside it and at the same time its function that I am using. But clicking the button inside my jqgrid it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: clickmeapproved is not defined`. Is there anything wrong with my code or the way that I am using them?. Same error with the disapproved button.

```
 afterInsertRow: function (rowid) {
              var obj = jQuery("#FiTATimeCorrectionV2List").getRowData(rowid);
              var FADTLSID = obj.FitaAssignDtlID;
              if (FADTLSID !== undefined) {
                  if (FADTLSID !== "") {
                      var btnApprove = "<input type = 'image' img alt='' src='../../Content/Images/newimages/check.png' style='height:20px;width:20px;'  style ='width: 90px' id='btnApproved" + rowid + "' onclick='clickmeapproved(" + rowid + " )' />"
                      var btnDisApprove = "<input type = 'image' img  alt='' src='../../Content/Images/newimages/delete.png' style='height:20px;width:20px;' style ='width: 90px' id='btnDisApproved" + rowid + "' onclick='clickmedisapproved(" + rowid + " )' />"
                      jQuery("#FiTATimeCorrectionV2List").setRowData(rowid, { FitaCorForApproval: btnApprove });
                      jQuery("#FiTATimeCorrectionV2List").setRowData(rowid, { FitaCorForDisApproval: btnDisApprove });
                      var temp = obj.FitaStatus;
                      if (temp == "Approved") {
                          $("#btnApproved" + rowid).hide();
                          $("#btnDisApproved" + rowid).hide();
                      }
                      else if (temp == "Disapproved") {
                          $("#btnApproved" + rowid).hide();
                          $("#btnDisApproved" + rowid).hide();
                      } else {
                          $("#btnApproved" + rowid).show();
                          $("#btnDisApproved" + rowid).show();
                      }
                  }
              }
          },
```

---

```
function clickmeapproved(rowid) {
var ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to approve the request of "+ globalFitaCorName +"?");
if (ans) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../Request/SaveFitaApproval?FAID=' + rowid,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Successfully approve!");
            $("#FiTATimeCorrectionV2List").trigger("reloadGrid");
            FiTATimeCorrectionV2(0);
            globalFitaCorName = "";
            $("#loader").hide();
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            $("#FiTATimeCorrectionV2List").trigger("reloadGrid");
            FiTATimeCorrectionV2(0);
            globalFitaCorName = "";
            $("#loader").hide();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "clickmeapproved" function does not have global scope. Check by typing "window.clickmeapproved" in the web inspector.

Comment: Global Scope? Sorry that's the first I know it.

Comment: browser in trying to find "clickmeapproved" function attached to window object.  Which it can't find. So you need to make sure "window.clickmeapproved" is working. You can learn about scopes in javascript here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: BTW.. Thanks for the help I just solve it now. I edit my code a bit. Wait i'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I use to solve my issue.

```
var btnApprove = "<input type = 'image' img alt='' src='../../Content/Images/newimages/check.png' style='height:20px;width:20px;'  style ='width: 90px' id='btnApproved" + rowid + "' />" 
var btnDisApprove = "<input type = 'image' img  alt='' src='../../Content/Images/newimages/delete.png' style='height:20px;width:20px;' style ='width: 90px' id='btnDisApproved" + rowid + "' />"
```

I exclude the button click from it.

```
$("#btnApproved" + rowid + "").click(function(){
   clickmeapproved(rowid);
});
$("#btnDisApproved" + rowid + "").click(function(){
   clickmedisapproved(rowid);
});
```